# Not able to see Customer service - Backoffice Migration Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a Hybris project in 5.7 and now we are upgrading to 6.7 .Now i have to work customer service cockpit .i have added customersupportbackoffice extension and build,restart, update done .

But when i log in using backoffice using  customer service credentials--> its showing blank page , Here am i missing some thing ???
I dont see customer support icon also and in perspective also..

It almost wasted my 2 days, Could any body please help me ..
[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question? Otherwise it would better be migrated to superuser.

Comment: HI @DirkHorsten , Thanks for your response , i tried with super user also .. but no use .. Any idea in the above question ?  I want to see Customer service in back office

Comment: Did you open orchestrator and click reset everything?